# How can I get a Spring @RestController to accept parameters in JSON format rather than www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Using Spring 4.1.7 on JDK 1.8, I have an @RestController class that looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class ServiceAController {

    public static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ServiceAController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/rest/servicea", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ServiceAResponse serviceA(@RequestParam(value="parmA", defaultValue="defaultParmA") String parmA,
            @RequestParam(value="parmB", defaultValue="defaultParmB") String parmB,
            @RequestParam(value="parmC", defaultValue="defaulParmC") String parmC) {
        LOG.info("Inside Service A handler: " + parmA + " B: "+ parmB + " C: "+ parmC);
}
```

When I send a POST to /rest/servicea from a javascript like this, everything works, and I see the values "a", "b", and "c" printed in my log:

```
    var data = {        
        "parmA": "a",
        "parmB": "b",
        "parmC": "c"
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./rest/servicea",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: submitAuthSuccess,
        error: submitAuthFailure 
    })
```

However, when I try to change the call from the javascript to this (to change the protocol to REST rather than www-urlencode), I get the default values (defaultParmA, defaultParmB, defaultParmC) in my log:

```
    var data = {        
        "parmA": "a",
        "parmB": "b",
        "parmC": "c"
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./rest/servicea",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        success: submitAuthSuccess,
        error: submitAuthFailure 
    })
```

I think I'm missing something in the @RestController class to get it to parse the JSON rather than expecting www-urlencoded data.

I tried changing the `@RequestMapping` annotation on the `serviceA` method to add the `consumes="application/json"` attribute, but that had no effect.

What can I change to make this work, using JSON rather than urlencoded data in the POST body?

Comment: It seems you've misunderstood what a request parameter represents. It's either a query parameter or a form parameter. You're not sending either in your second example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`@RequestParam`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) javadoc states

> Annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to
>   a web request parameter.

This is retrieved through the various `ServletRequest` methods for request parameters. For example, [`ServletRequest#getParameterMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap--) which states

> Request parameters are extra information sent with the request. For
>   HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted
>   form data.

In your second snippet, you aren't sending either. You're sending JSON in the request body.

Spring has a mechanism (it has many, and custom ones) for deserializing that into the data you expect. The standard solution is [`@RequestBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html), assuming you have an appropriately registered `HttpMessageConverter` that can handle the JSON. Spring automatically registers [`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) if you have Jackson 2 on the classpath, which can correctly deserialize JSON into Java POJO types.

The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody) gives a number of examples and explains how you would use it. With JSON, you could define a POJO type with fields that correspond to the ones you send

```
class RequestPojo {
    private String paramA;
    private String paramB;
    private String paramC;
    // and corresponding getters and setters
}
```

and add a `@RequestBody` annotated parameter of this type to your handler method

```
public ServiceAResponse serviceA(@RequestBody RequestPojo pojo) {
    pojo.getParamB(); // do something
    return ...;
}
```

Jackson lets you define, through annotations or through configuration of the `ObjectMapper`, how to deal with absent values.

`@RestController` is not involved here. As its javadoc states,

> Types that carry this annotation are treated as controllers where
>   `@RequestMapping` methods assume `@ResponseBody` semantics by default.

Comment: Thanks much for the well-written answer.  This taught me what I needed to understand to get it done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are passing a single JSON object at this point, rather than a set of parameters, hence Spring cannot match what you're sending to any of the parameters you've provided.

Try

```
@RequestBody List<ListUnit> listOfUnits
```

instead of @RequestParam